# Why is this MongoDB document being generated with the same nanoid?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

To start, I have already found a fix but what I need to know is why the bug happens.
In the following two examples MongoDB the documents are being generated with the same id and date respectively.

```
id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    default: nanoid(),
    immutable: true,
  },
```

```
dateCreated: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now(),
    immutable: true,
  }
```

In the following two examples, every document is being generated with a different id and date of creation

```
id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    default: () => nanoid(),
    immutable: true,
  },
```

```
dateCreated: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: () => Date.now(),
    immutable: true,
  }
```

I know this has something to do with value versus reference in javascript, but I cannot pinpoint exactly why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass this in an object:

```
default: nanoid(),
```

the javascript interpreter will first execute `nanoid()` and assign the returned value to the `default` field.

This would essentially be the same as:

```
const newId = nanoid();
...
id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    default: newId
    immutable: true,
  },
```

This is effectively setting the default to a static value.

Note that you could probably get the behavior you wanted by not including the `()`, such as

```
id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    default: nanoid,
    immutable: true,
  },
```